# Fastest way to recursively list all the files in a directory

Tags: shell, files, find

I'm trying to get the relative path of all the files in a directory. It can run on hundreds of thousands of files so I need it to be fast.

I've tried `find .` and `rg --files` (**`rg`** being [**`ripgrep`**](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)) and `rg` is roughly 6 times faster.

Is there a native way to do this better or even a faster tool ?

Comment: `tree -if --noreport` seems pretty quick in my tests.

Comment: @DopeGhoti `find .` is as fast as it gets for a sequential traversal. Ripgrep manages to be faster by parallelizing the traversal, which may be faster or slower depending on how the underlying storage copes with concurrent access (expect a speedup when reading from cache or from SSD, but a slowdown when reading from rotating media). Is `tree` parallelized? If not it won't beat `find`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I'm not sure I agree with your analysis. Even if you're reading from a hard disk, batching a bunch of reads together should permit the I/O scheduler to be smarter about how it reads from disk, e.g., by grouping together reads that are closer together on the disk. (For ripgrep to take advantage of that, you'd need to bump up the thread count to increase the number of simultaneous workers crawling the directory. That can be done with the `-j` flag.)

Comment: Also, ripgrep's recursive iterator is available as a Rust library: https://docs.rs/ignore/0.2.0/ignore/struct.WalkParallel.html

Comment: @BurntSushi5 Thanks for your work! Any negative side effects to settings -j to 12 ?

Comment: Absolutely. Depends on number of cores of your CPU. It will increase startup times (so would be bad for quick searches), and could increase the variability of the order of the output.

Comment: @BurntSushi5, I'm not sure that I'd qualify a quick comment after some cursory tests with no data to back up the claim "analysis", which is why after doing said cursory tests, my feedback was in the form of a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Errmm, right, sorry. I had meant to @ Gilles. :-)

Comment: From `gitstatusd `: https://github.com/romkatv/gitstatus/blob/master/docs/listdir.md#fast-directory-listing

Comment: To compare like-to-like, that should be `find . -type f` vs `rg -g '*' --files .`

Answer (score 1):

This cheats and assumes you have an updated location database (like [plocate](https://plocate.sesse.net/)), but it should be the fastest simply because you're parsing through a cache of the directory contents.

```
locate "$PWD/*" |awk -v len="${#PWD}" '{ print substr($0, len+2) }'
```

The `locate` database updates daily, so you might have to run `sudo updatedb` beforehand, which will obviously take a while since it's indexing your entire filesystem (and probably not as quickly as ripgrep), but if you need to do this a few times, caching it once is still the way to go.

The `awk` code prints the hits relative to the given path. You could make this a function like this:

```
# Usage: indir [DIRECTORY]
# Show recursive contents of DIRECTORY (defaults to current directory)
indir() {
  d="$(readlink -f "${1:-$PWD}")"
  locate "$d/*" |awk -v len="${#d}" '{ print substr($0, len+2) }'
}
```

[`readlink -f`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/readlink-invocation.html) (from GNU Coreutils) will canonicalize your input, so you can run `indir .` or `indir ../foo` and it'll still work (though the output will be relative to the DIRECTORY, so it'll show `../foo/bar/baz` as `bar/baz`).

As noted in the comments to this answer, you will run into issues if there are globbing characters (`?` or `*` or `[…]`) in the querying path name. You can defeat that by escaping them with backslashes (though be aware that this changes the length).

Alternatively, you could do this with GNU grep if it is compiled with libpcre support:

```
# Usage: indir [DIRECTORY]
# Show recursive contents of DIRECTORY (defaults to current directory)
indir() {
  d="$(readlink -f "${1:-$PWD}")"
  locate "$d/*" |grep -Po "^\Q$d/\E\K.+"
}
```

This runs grep with PCRE and only prints the matching content. The regex is a bit complicated (see also [regex101 explanation](https://regex101.com/r/zj2JB9/4)). It matches only at the beginning of a line (`^`), then becomes a literal string match (`\Q…\E` inhibits regex interpretation between `\Q` and `\E`), then `\K` denotes the beginning of what should be reported as the match. The final `.+` matches all content after that path, which is the only thing grep reports. I put a literal `/` inside the `\Q…\E` to ensure we don't match the directory name itself, though this also ensures we don't match a different path, like `/path/to/dirt` matching a query for `/path/to/dir`.

Comment: That assumes `$PWD` doesn't contain wildcard or regex operators (and file paths don't contain newlines). `.` at least is common in file paths. See also `locate "$PWD/*"` (also affected by file paths containing wildcards).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas – I figured the risk from `.` was managed by the fact that it's also the argument to `locate` and the risk from other regex items was trivial, but you're right. I almost went with `grep -P "^\Q$PWD\E\b"` to resolve that, but then I wanted to use `awk` to make it relative as requested. I didn't know you could wildcard in `locate`. That certainly seems better. I'll update to that effect.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas – I've updated it with a `grep -P` solution that simplifies this while controlling for your wildcard/glob concern.